# Python: class method not getting called by another method in the same class

Tags: python, methods, scope

First off, I am not terribly experienced with Python, so I apologise if this is an overly elementary question. I have tried searching for a solution on Google and SO, and come up with nothing.

I am currently working on a cryptocurrency trading platform, which receives market updates over WAMP using Autobahn. However, I am having an issue with one of my class methods. The code in question is as follows:

```
class TradeClient(ApplicationSession):
    exchange = "NULL"   

    def eventProcessor(self, event):
        print("eventProcessor called")
        print("market event received: {}".format(event))

    def onJoin(self, details):
        print("{} client session ready".format(exchange))

        def marketEvent(event):
            print("marketEvent called")
            self.processEvent(event)

            [...]
```

Now, obviously, TradeClient is a class which is intended to be a superclass, and the exchange variable and eventProcessor method are intended to be overwritten in the subclasses for compatibility with different exchanges (for arbitrage, among other things). The marketEvent method is getting called fine, but the eventProcessor method is not.

Is this a scoping issue? It seems as though it shouldn't be, and passing eventProcessor an argument of event[:] makes no difference.

EDIT:

The marketEvent function is nested within onJoin. I apologise for not stating explicitly that this was the case - I had assumed that the indentation would make this clear. The correct, complete code is pasted below. The reason that I wish to call eventProcessor is to make the parsing of the JSONs easy to override for different exchanges.

```
from autobahn.asyncio.wamp import ApplicationSession
from autobahn.asyncio.wamp import ApplicationRunner
from asyncio import coroutine 
import sys
import json
from io import StringIO

poloniex_URL = "wss://api.poloniex.com"    

class TradeClient(ApplicationSession):

    exchange = "NULL"

    def eventProcessor(self, event):
        print("eventProcessor called")
        print("market event received: {}".format(event))

    def onJoin(self, details):
        print("{} client session ready".format(self.exchange))

        def marketEvent(event):
            print("marketEvent called")
            self.eventProcessor(self, event)

        # Read in configuration files
        try:
            pairs = [line.strip() for line in open("conf/" + self.exchange + ".conf")]
        except:
            print("Configuration file not found for {}!".format(self.exchange))
            sys.exit(1)

        # Subscribe to each currency pair / topic in the conf file
        for pair in pairs:
            try:
                yield from self.subscribe(marketEvent, pair)
                print("subscribed to {} on {}".format(pair, self.exchange))
            except Exception as e:
                print("could not subscribe to {} on {}: {}".format(pair, exchange, e))
                sys.exit(1)

class PoloniexClient(TradeClient):
    exchange = "poloniex"

poloniex_runner = ApplicationRunner(url = poloniex_URL, realm = "realm1")
poloniex_runner.run(PoloniexClient)
```

Comment: The indentation of the method ``marketEvent`` is wrong. Outdent it for 4 spaces to the left. Second, in this method a method ``processEvent`` is called, which is not defined before. You have ``eventProcessor``, but you call ``processEvent``.

Comment: In this case, marketEvent must be nested within onJoin, because otherwise it will not be triggered by the event in question. Also, ironically, I renamed processEvent in an attempt to make it more clear for the purposes of posting it here. It still does not work when the names match.